# Android save layout state

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a question about saving the state of a layout file in Android. For example: I have a button and when I click the button an image appears. But when I rotate my Android device the image is disappeared. So how do I save the state (visible/invisible) of the image in the layout? I know I have to put this in the Android manifest at the activity:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

How I interact with my ImageView:

```
Button imageloader = (Button) findViewById(R.id.imageloader);
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv);
imageloader.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {            
    public void onClick(View v) {
    iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
```

Comment: Look into onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState().

Comment: I did, but everywhere people are talking about savedInstanceState.putDouble, savedInstanceState.putString etc. But I just want to save the state of a layout

Comment: Post how you load your image and I'll help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can save and restore the visibility of your ImageView `iv` like this:

```
ImageView iv;
...

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    iv.setVisibility(savedInstanceState.getInt("Image Visibility", View.GONE));
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putInt("Image Visibility", iv.getVisibility());
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

This way you do not need to use the `configChanges` attribute in the manifest. You can remove that.